# Azure Logic Apps - Issues with trigger being when Item is created in SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I use logic apps frequently, but always with a time based trigger.  Trying to set one up that triggers when an item is added to a SQL table.  Below are parameters - it just doesn't seem to be working.  I am positive there are items being added to these query results at least every half hour, but it never seems to trigger.  Any thoughts on what i might be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Anonymous and [v-alzhan-msft](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/83144). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

When invoking triggers, we have the following limitations:

- A ROWVERSION column is required for OnUpdatedItems
- An **IDENTITY** column is required for **OnNewItems**

So, if you don't have an IDENTITY column, create one and it should work. That column will auto-increase by definition. [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can refer to ["When an item is created" trigger (SQL in Azure) not working](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/quot-When-an-item-is-created-quot-trigger-SQL-in-Azure-not/td-p/414776)
and [SQL connectors - Known issues and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#known-issues-and-limitations)